# unable to get full video URL from sax xml parsing in android app

Tags: android, saxparser, xml-parsing

As I am new to Android development,
I have used SAX xml parsing in my Android app.
It is working fine but in URL when it got "&" symbol it simply discard the next all url part.
I think not sure is this problem of charcaters method of that `DefaultHandler` class?

```
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)throws SAXException {

        if (currentElement) 
        {

            currentValue = new String(ch, start, length);
                    currentElement = false;

        }
}
```

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace "&" characters in you XML with escape sequences. XML file shouldn't contain "&" characters out of CDATA fields.

Comment: in xml how i could replace "&" with escape sequence dynamically if you have any code snippet then plz provide....

Comment: The best way is to tell you source of xml to fix the issue on it's side. If it isn't possible, guess simple search and replace in XML string should work.

Comment: Something like this? =)

final String fixedXml = initialXml.replace("&", "&amp;");